# How to get a folder's creator in SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a web part for SharePoint 2010 and I would like to know how to get the user that created a certain folder (SPFolder). I was able to get the doc libs creator, web, etc, but I had no luck with folders.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.item.aspx) property.

```
SPFieldUserValue createdBy = 
    new SPFieldUserValue(web, folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString());
```

Comment: You save my life!!